# SAS ERROR IN A PROC HPBIN.... ERROR: class variable

Tags: sas

I RAN THIS QUERY AND GET THIS ERROR MESSAGE:

`ERROR: num_bankrupt_iva  is class variable, only interval variable is supported.`

```
/*WoE and IV Analysis*/
proc hpbin data=train numbin=5;
    input monthly_installment loan_balance bureau_score2    num_bankrupt_iva time_since_bankrupt
    num_ccj2 time_since_ccj ccj_amount  num_bankrupt    num_iva min_months_since_bankrupt
    ltv arrears_months  origination_date maturity_date arrears_status   arrears_segment 
    mob remaining_mat loan_term live_status repaid_status /*year quarter*/ 
    month worst_arrears_status max_arrears_12m  recent_arrears_date months_since_2mia
    avg_mia_6m max_arrears_bal_6m max_mia_6m    avg_bal_6m  avg_bureau_score_6m
    cc_util annual_income emp_length months_since_recent_cc_delinq;
    ods output mapping=mapping;
run;
```

and the LOG shows these errors:

```
NOTE: Binning methods: BUCKET BINNING .
ERROR: num_bankrupt_iva is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: time_since_bankrupt is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: time_since_ccj is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: ccj_amount is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: num_bankrupt is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: num_iva is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: min_months_since_bankrupt is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: recent_arrears_date is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: months_since_2mia is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
ERROR: avg_bureau_score_6m is class variable, only interval variable is supported.
NOTE: The number of bins is: 5.
NOTE: The HPBIN procedure is executing in single-machine mode.
```

Comment: Can you provide the dataset train you used with your code as per a reproducible example? The error message seems to be related to the type of variables you've used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all of those variables in the log are specified as characters in your input dataset. You will need to convert them to numeric using the `input()` function. Or, you could multiply them by 1 and let SAS automatically do the conversion.

```
data want;
    set have;
    numvar = input(classvar, 8.);
    numvar2 = 1*classvar;
run;
```